# What is the meaning of "all being well"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> After lunch I usually review my cases then visit the patients in the TB ward. **All being well**, I'm out of the clinic by 6pm. We eat dinner around seven. Unfortunately, there's often a power-cut at this time, so we quite often have to eat in the dark. Still, I guess that's all part of the adventure!

<sup>[[Source]](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY2OSZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY2OSZlZD0yMDE0LTEyLTAxVDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4)</sup>

What is the meaning of "all being well" in the above context?

Comment: It's a participle clause meaning "**In the case that** all is well".

Comment: And syntactically it is an [absolute clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).

Comment: "All being well" means "if everything goes the way that I want/expect it to"

Comment: I disagree with closing this as answerable with a dictionary. Searching for "all being well" doesn't have clearly understandable results, especially because "being" can be interpreted as an entity and not a participle.

Comment: @ColleenV - Moreover, in this context, conceivably, _all being well_ could mean, "If everything goes well," but it could also mean, "If all the patients are doing well."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'All being well' means 'If everything is as it should be' or 'If everything goes smoothly.'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please add an explanation and citation (of a dictionary or other reliable source) to improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's like **"All is well"** that means *everything is just fine*.